# How to list all files in a remote/server directory

Tags: android, file

I'm making an android application that requires me to download all of the images from a remote directory locally in the /files path of the app. I need to know how to get a list of all of the files (all images) in that directory so I can download them all to the phone. I found the code to list the files in a local directory, but I need to know how to do the same thing for a remote directory (the directory is an http directory that requires no login)

```
String path = "."; 

String files;
File folder = new File(path);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
{

 if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
 {
   files = listOfFiles[i].getName();
   System.out.println(files);
 }
}
```

Also, I'm using this working code to download the images once I get the name of them in the directory.

```
private void storeImage(String filename)
{
  FileOutputStream out = null;
  try
  {
    URL url = new URL(Consts.IMAGES_BASE_URL + filename);
    InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    out = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().toString(), filename);
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);

    if(isPNG(filename))//isPNG just parses out the extension
      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, out);
    else if(isJPG(filename))
      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);

  } catch (MalformedURLException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {
    try
    {
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you want is not necessarily possible (it depends on whether the Web server has any concept of serving you the directory listing) and has very little to do with Android.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'll have to figure out something else.

Comment: @CommonsWare: hi, how to do this if directory listing is possible?

Comment: @A.M.D: You ask the Web developers how they are formatting the directory listing and what URL to use for it. Then, you download the directory listing from that URL and parse it based on however they formatted it.

Comment: Thankyou for replying... i need to display the files in this folder: http://thepetraministries.org/Sermons/2011/ ... i can ask the developers if it is still required... it would be great if can do it otherwise...